# DataRows not serializable in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, serialization

My application uses DataRows and they are not serializable. Is there a workaround for the same?

Answer (score 3):

Put them into a data table and that into a dataset. That should serialize correctly.

Comment: +1, but you can just put them into a DataTable, since the DataTable is serializable as well.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure. IIRC it wasn't at one point in .NET history.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to create a `List<object>`.

Then fill the List scanning `DataRows`, and serialize List.

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataTable dt = dataRow.Table.Clone();
        dt.ImportRow(dataRow);
        dt.AcceptChanges();

        string xml = string.Empty;
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            dt.WriteXml(writer);
            xml = writer.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.